# Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST

Tags: php

I get the following error: `Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\includes\class-insert.php on line 47` when trying to access my class-insert.php page (or most of my other pages).
This code is from the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wgbmgf84ZOo and can be found here: http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/lesson/how-to-create-a-social-network-using-php/

**class-insert.php**:

```
<?php
        require_once('class-db.php');

        if ( !class_exists('INSERT') ) {
            class INSERT {
                public function update_user($user_id, $postdata) {
                    global $db;

                    $table = 's_users';

                    $query = "
                                    UPDATE $table
                                    SET user_email='$postdata[user_email]', user_pass='$postdata[user_pass]', user_nicename='$postdata[user_nicename]'
                                    WHERE ID=$user_id
                                ";

                    return $db->update($query);
                }

                public function add_friend($user_id, $friend_id) {
                    global $db;

                    $table = 's_friends';

                    $query = "
                                    INSERT INTO $table (user_id, friend_id)
                                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$friend_id')
                                ";

                    return $db->insert($query);
                }

                public function remove_friend($user_id, $friend_id) {
                    global $db;

                    $table = 's_friends';

                    $query = "
                                    DELETE FROM $table 
                                    WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
                                    AND friend_id = '$friend_id'
                                ";

                    return $db->insert($query);
                }

                public function add_status($user_id, $_POST) {
                    global $db;

                    $table = 's_status';

                    $query = "
                                    INSERT INTO $table (user_id, status_time, status_content)
                                    VALUES ($user_id, '$_POST[status_time]', '$_POST[status_content]')
                                ";

                    return $db->insert($query);
                }

                public function send_message($_POST) {
                    global $db;

                    $table = 's_messages';

                    $query = "
                                    INSERT INTO $table (message_time, message_sender_id, message_recipient_id, message_subject, message_content)
                                    VALUES ('$_POST[message_time]', '$_POST[message_sender_id]', '$_POST[message_recipient_id]', '$_POST[message_subject]', '$_POST[message_content]')
                                ";

                    return $db->insert($query);
                }
            }
        }

        $insert = new INSERT;
    ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514711/wordpress-theme-error-fatal-error-cannot-re-assign-auto-global-variable-post

Comment: It looks as though you cannot use a super global as a parameter after PHP 5.4 here is the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal variable. You don't need to declare it at all.

Comment: @Chitowns24 Thanks for the links, but why replace `$_POST` with `$_my_post` (or similar), and would I need to declare the $_my_post variable?

Comment: You do not need to declare function arguments, or any variables in PHP for that matter.

Comment: So I just omit the $_POST, and leave what is already there?

Comment: @WalkOfLife yes. superglobal variables are already there and don't need any call or decleration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a superglobal as the variable name for a function argument. You can still pass a superglobal to the function if you use an alternate name or you could remove the superglobal from the argument list and just access it anyways, since it's available everywhere.

[List of superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Option 1:

```
function print_post( $post_data ){
    print_r($post_data);
}
print_post($_POST);
```

Option 2: (bad form)

```
function print_post(){
    print_r($_POST);
}
print_post();
```

Comment: _You can still pass a superglobal to the function if you use an alternate name or you could remove the superglobal from the argument list_ Thanks for the reply Michael, but I'm still confused (I checked the link). Could you provide an example?

Comment: I've provided 2 example functions that handle the $_POST superglobal. Note that it is bad form to access shared variables - it is best to minimize [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 1):

All I did was to remove the $_POST in the function arg and that settles the problem. you could remove the superglobal from the argument list and just access it anyways, since it's available everywhere.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, you cannot use a superglobal as the parameter to a function, $_POST is globally accessible. So you don't have to pass to your function.